# Arabic Fonts in Case Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which I am using **Case function** and getting `???` instead of arbic words here is my query please anyone can help me out on this problem

```
case when main = 'mosque' then cast('مسجد' as nvarchar(50))

case when main = 'mosque' then cast('مسجد' as nvarchar(50))

case when main = 'mosque' then convert(nvarchar(50),'مسجد')
```

Still getting `???` in rows

مسجد

Comment: Unicode literals need the `N` prefix, otherwise they are treated as ASCII. There's no reason to cast to `nvarchar`. Just use `case when main = 'mosque' then N'مسجد' `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unicode string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#unicode-strings) use the N prefix. Without it the string literal is interpreted as an ASCII literal. The strings get mangled before `cast` is called.

Try :

```
case when main = 'mosque' then N'مسجد'      
     ...
END
```

or

```
case main when 'mosque' then N'مسجد' 
          ...
END
```

There's no need to cast to `nvarchar` as the strings are already nvarchar

Comment: what is N prefix is ??

Comment: @AsadAmjad did you click the link provided in the answer?  It's explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Use symbol N before values of nvarchar datatype.
In your example should be like:

```
case when main = 'mosque' then cast(N'مسجد' as nvarchar(50))

case when main = 'mosque' then cast(N'مسجد' as nvarchar(50))

case when main = 'mosque' then convert(nvarchar(50),N'مسجد')
```

Comment: There's no need for `cast` when the `N` prefix is used